# Requesting new permissions fail handling

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Login and asking permission works just fine. But there is one problem: I need to ask publish permission when user wants to share some date from my app. Here is my code:

```
ParseFacebookUtils.getSession().requestNewPublishPermissions(new NewPermissionsRequest((Activity) context,
            Arrays.asList(Permissions.Extended.PUBLISH_ACTIONS, Permissions.Extended.PUBLISH_STREAM))
        .setCallback(new StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (!arePublishPermissionsEnabled(session)) {
                    inflow.setChecked(false);
                    facebook.setChecked(false);
                    twitter.setChecked(false);
                } 
            }
        }));
```

The problem is in handling situation when user canceled request or there is a loss of network connection. In this case I need to do some changes in my UI, but method call is calling only when session state is changed (e.g. granted new permissions) and I can't properly changed my UI. Is anyone faced such problem?

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using? I believe 3.0.1 addresses this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void requestPublishPermissions(Session session) {
    List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions", "publish_stream");
    if (session != null) {
        pendingAnnounce = true;
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);

        newPermissionsRequest.setRequestCode(REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE);
        Session mSession = Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(this);
        mSession.addCallback(callback);
        mSession.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
    }
}
```